# Minlength in Textarea not working

Tags: c#, jquery, html, textarea

How to set `minlength = 2` for `Textarea`. I tried in my code but it doesn't seem to be working. I am getting an error as unknown attribute. Is there any way to set minlength of textarea as "2" ? Thanks in advance. 
I even tried `pattern = {2,}` but it didn't work.

```
<textarea name="Remarks" onchange="CheckValidChars(this);" onblur="CheckValidChars(this);" onkeypress="return isValidChars(event);" id="Remarks" maxlength="700" minlength = "2" required cols="100" rows="6" ng-model="vm.EditRef_OCBUI.Remarks"></textarea>
```

Comment: there is a typo in `pattern=".{2,}"`

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=minlength

Comment: Yeah I checked it out. But minlength & pattern are not working for me. So i reposted the question . Duplicate answer is not helping me. I already checked that duplicate answer before i posted this question the first time. So you can stop down voting before even checking that I already tried tags as mentioned in duplicate answer.

Comment: Well, it seems to be working for everyone else. Can you include a snippet (use the `<>` button in the question editor) in your question that shows that it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a validation with jQuery.

jQuery example:

```
$('#formID').submit(function(e){
    if($('#Remarks').val().length < 3){
       e.preventdefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: formID is "textarea id" ?

Comment: No. It's the form id.

I'm handling the form submit event.

Don't you have a form?

When do you want to validate? On submit? On blur?

Answer (score -3):

You can add minlength simply...........`<textarea maxlength="20" minlength="5"></textarea>`

Comment: try and look at the OP's html, it is already added